# Sequences simple problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the sum of the series.
$$1.2.3+2.3.4+3.4.5+.....n$$

My answer.
$$n(n+1)(n+2)$$
$$=n^3+3n^2+2n
[(n(n+1)/2)]^2+n(n+1)(2n+1)/2+n(n+1)
n^2(n+1)^2/4+n(n+1)(2n+1)/2+n(n+1)
(n+1) [n^2(n+1)/4+n(2n+1)/2+n]$$
Again,
$$(n+1)/2 [n^2(n+1)/2+n(2n+1) + n/2]
= (n+1)/2 [(n^3+n^2/2) +2n^2+n+n/2)$$
$$=n+1/2[((n^3+n^2+3n)/2)+2n^2)]$$
Is it correct to this point?
Or can i reduce it as 
$$(n+1)/2*n(n^2+3n+2)$$

Comment: Is the last term of the series $n(n+1)(n+2)$ or $(n-2)(n-1)n$?

Comment: Your equations doesn't look correct-$\begin{align*}
  n(n+1)(n+2) &= n^3+3n^2+2n \Bigl[\bigl(n(n+1)/2\bigr)\Bigr]^2+n(n+1)(2n+1)/2+n(n+1) \\
              &=(n+1)/2\bigl[n^2(n+1)+n(2n+1)+n\bigr] n+1/2(n^3+3n^ 2+2n).
\end{align*}$ how did you get these?

Answer (score 2):

We can write $$\displaystyle S=(1\cdot 2\cdot 3)+(2\cdot 3\cdot 4)+..........\bf{n-terms } = \sum^{n}_{r=1}r\cdot (r+1)\cdot (r+2)$$

$$\displaystyle S= \sum^{n}_{r=1}[r^3+3r^2+2r] = \sum^{n}_{r=1}r^3+3\sum^{n}_{r=1}r^2+2\sum^{n}_{r=1}r$$

Now Using $$\bullet\; \displaystyle \sum^{n}_{r=1}r=\frac{r(r+1)}{2}$$ and $$\bullet\; \displaystyle \sum^{n}_{r=1}r^2=\frac{r(r+1)(2r+1)}{6}$$

and $$\bullet\; \displaystyle \sum^{n}_{r=1}r^3=\left[\frac{r(r+1)}{2}\right]^2$$

So we get $$\displaystyle S =\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}+3\cdot \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+2\cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

For all integer $n\geq 1$, let
$$
  S_n = 1\times 2\times 3 + 2\times 3\times 4 + \dots + n(n + 1)(n + 2).
$$
We rewrite it as
$$
\begin{align*}
  S_n &= \frac{3!}{0!} + \frac{4!}{1!} + \dots + \frac{(n+2)!}{(n-1)!} \\
      &= 3! 
         \left(
           \binom{3}{0} + \binom{4}{1} + \dots + \binom{n+2}{n-1}
         \right).
\end{align*}
$$
Using the well-known identity
$$
  \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{k+i}{i} = \binom{k+n+1}{n},
$$
we obtain
$$
  S_n = 3! \binom{n+3}{n-1} = \frac{1}{4}n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3).
$$